# Is PIL capable of repairing truncated images? If not, can this feature be added?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a project that uses node.js to upload pictures onto a cloud server. Then, a Python script rotates and resizes them with PIL. For some reason, there are always a few images (jpg/jpeg) that throw the error about the image being truncated.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1960, in save 
      self.load()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 238, in load 
      len(b))
    OSError: image file is truncated (28 bytes not processed)
```

From my research, most people just use try/except to find these bad images and get new ones from the source (which in my case are Android and iPhones). However, I am able to open these pictures with the browser, and other image programs (And they look just fine!). So, it seems like most applications can deal with a certain amount of image corruption. I am aware that I can force PIL to process truncated images, but then they have nasty areas of grey.

```
    LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

Is there a way to avoid these (sometimes huge %) grey areas or actually have PIL fix the image?

If not, can I add that as a feature request? I might even be able to take on the challenge, but I don't know how difficult it is. Would anyone be willing to guide me?

It would be fantastic if there was just a tiny (28 Byte) grey (or the colors of the nearby pixels) box of what is truncated, instead of the entire rest of the image. Some images that I process will be about 90% grey box.

Or, does anyone know of another Python module or CLI application (maybe GIMP) that can deal with a minor corruption issue and re-save the image.

I have tried re-opening the image when there is an error, but that doesn't seem to help.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way you can post one of these corrupted images so we can see the problem ourselves?

Comment: The obvious place for your request is on the opencv github issues area, as that’s presumably the main place the developers hang out. Have you tried posting there?

Comment: Requesting libraries is off-topic.

Comment: @barny even though there's an explicit request for an alternate library, I think they'd be happy with a solution that makes their current choice work properly.  But that does lead to a follow-up, which version of `PIL` is being used?

Comment: Durp I mean the pillow github issues, not opencv.

Comment: @barny PIL.__version__ is '4.3.0'. I thought I saw somewhere that the developers want requests for features on stack overflow. I will double check for a better area to ask.

Comment: @MarkRansom I will try to get you a picture that is creating problems for me soon. Oh I should have marked my last comment to you also, about the version. 4.3.0